# PyQt Change Active Widget Highlight Colour

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, highlight, qtstylesheets

I have a PyQt window with a custom stylesheet.
On MacOS the QLineEdit is highlighted in blue when it is active, which ruins the stylesheet I am using. Is there any way to either stop this from happening or change the highlight colour that is used?

[image: Window]

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it using the QPalette:

```
le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
pal = le.palette()
pal.setColor(
    QtGui.QPalette.Active, QtGui.QPalette.Highlight, QtGui.QColor("black")
)
le.setPalette(pal)
```